# How to implement the avatar selection screen like this in android without using any library?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, carousel

this is my first question here. I am trying implement similar avatar selection screen for my college project. I searched almost everywhere and it seems like it can be done using viewpager. I tried but cant achieve similar effect. I have problem is showing all child in at the same time. and also i cant able to achieve the select avatar scaled in high and rest in low. Please help me out, i want to implement quickly as possible without using any library because i want to understand how it can be implemented without it as of now. Thanks in advance.

[image]

I have tried to create a viewpager with 3 images. This is my implementation.

MainActivity.java with MyPagerAdapter

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
    pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}

public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                return FirstFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.a);
            case 1:
                return SecondFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.b);
            case 2:
                return ThirdFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.c);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/myViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have 3 Fragements. This is one of the fragement.

FirstFragment.java

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
private int image;

public FirstFragment() {

}

public static FirstFragment newInstance(int resImage) {
    FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("image", resImage);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    image = getArguments().getInt("image", 0);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.firstImg);
    imageView.setImageResource(image);
    return view;
}

}
```

This is fragment_first.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/firstImg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You're asking: _Tell me how to do my job_. This is not how you should work here. You have to provide some of your thoughts on how it is done. Look at the **animation** - yes, it seems like an animation, right? On set of ImageView? Could be. So check MaterialDesign animations / Transitions. That's at least something I can tell from provided information.

Comment: I have edited my question and attached the progress so far. Actually i ended up asking here because none of the sources helped me to achieve similar effect. I read about carousel effect and how to make 3 items appear simultaneously using getPageWidth() and also using pager.setPageMargin(). But still i dont have the desired result. And yes Thank you so much for replying. I am new here so i apologize for any mistakes that doesnt fit according to rules of stackoverflow, I just needed some help.

Comment: If its a animation, can it be achieved using viewpager. I mean it is possible or i am just trying in vain?